# How to show all fields while SUM them and show?

Tags: php, mysql, sum

I have a problem with showing all names that are grouped by, for example:

This is my table:

```
IMEPRIIMEK  REZULTAT  EKIPA
------------------------------
Ela         256       e13e01
Joe         218       e13e01
Tim         198       e13e01
Dan         265       e13e02
Jim         256       e13e02
Kim         215       e13e02
```

With my code that I have made it I get this result:

```
#  EKIPA  TOTAL  IMEPRIIMEK
-------------------------------
                 Dan
1  e13e02  736   Jim
                 Kim
------------------------
                 Ela
2  e13e01  672   Joe 
                 Tim
```

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("paradox", $con);

$result2 = mysql_query("SELECT NazivEkipe, ImePriimek, Rezultat,
                        SUM(Rezultat) AS 'total'
                        FROM tekmovanje
                        WHERE NazivEkipe='e13e01' OR NazivEkipe='e13e02' OR NazivEkipe='e13e03' OR NazivEkipe='e13e04' OR NazivEkipe='e13e05'
                        GROUP BY NazivEkipe
                        ORDER BY total DESC") or die(mysql_error());
$rank = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result2))
{
$rank++; 
?>

<tr align="center" valign="middle">
     <td rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $rank; ?></td>

     <td rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle" style="font-weight: bold; color: #008AFF;"><?php echo $row['total']; ?></td>

     <td rowspan="3" align="center" valign="middle"><?php echo $row['NazivEkipe']; ?></td>
<tr align="center" valign="middle">
  <td align="center" valign="middle" ><?php echo $row['ImePriimek']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

</table>
```

Help me, thank you for your answers.

PS: This is for personal usage and it **will not go online**, so I don't care about SQL injection or doing this with PDO MySQLi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing the table tag `<table>`

try this

```
   SELECT Ekipa , ImePriimek, Rezultat,
                    SUM(Rezultat) AS total
                    FROM tekmovanje
                    WHERE Ekipa in ('e13e01','e13e02','e13e03','e13e04','e13e05')
                    GROUP BY Ekipa 
                    ORDER BY total DESC
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4798d/6)

or this if you will group by `ImePriimek` to show all users

```
   SELECT Ekipa , ImePriimek, Rezultat,
                    SUM(Rezultat) AS total
                    FROM tekmovanje
                    WHERE Ekipa in ('e13e01','e13e02','e13e03','e13e04','e13e05')
                    GROUP BY Ekipa ,ImePriimek
                    ORDER BY total DESC
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4798d/7)

EDIT .i think this is what you want get

try this

```
    SELECT Ekipa , group_concat(ImePriimek) as IMEPRIIMEK, Rezultat,
                    sum(Rezultat) AS total
                    FROM tekmovanje
                    WHERE Ekipa in ('e13e01','e13e02','e13e03','e13e04','e13e05')
                    GROUP BY Ekipa
                    ORDER BY total DESC
```

RESULT

```
   _______________________________________
  |  EKIPA  IMEPRIIMEK    REZULTAT TOTAL  |
  | ______________________________________|
  | e13e02  Dan,Jim,Kim     265     726   |
  | e13e01  Ela,Joe,Tim     256     672   |
  |_______________________________________|
```

[**look demo here**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fc6d/3)

Comment: This is just like my result, it have to show all names which have e13e01 ore13e02...

Comment: I just saw now its not showing total, its just showing result by name? how to fix that?

Comment: total of what ? can u give me your wished result u want get ?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just this query?

```
SELECT EKIPA, sum(REZULTAT), GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IMEPRIIMEK)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY EKIPA
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the totalResult for every `EKIPA`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.totalResult
FROM    tableName a
        INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  EKIPA, SUM(REZULTAT) totalResult
            FROM    tableName 
            GROUP   BY EKIPA
        ) b ON a.EKIPA = b.EKIPA
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5318e/1)

Result

```
╔════════════╦══════════╦════════╦═════════════╗
║ IMEPRIIMEK ║ REZULTAT ║ EKIPA  ║ TOTALRESULT ║
╠════════════╬══════════╬════════╬═════════════╣
║ Ela        ║      256 ║ e13e01 ║         672 ║
║ Joe        ║      218 ║ e13e01 ║         672 ║
║ Tim        ║      198 ║ e13e01 ║         672 ║
║ Dan        ║      265 ║ e13e02 ║         736 ║
║ Jim        ║      256 ║ e13e02 ║         736 ║
║ Kim        ║      215 ║ e13e02 ║         736 ║
╚════════════╩══════════╩════════╩═════════════╝
```

Comment: It shows only first name 3 times? but its good becose its showing in 3 rows

Comment: @perofurid every row has different name. did you check the fiddle?

Comment: fiddle is a link for demonstration. is that what you want? `:D` or do you want me to explain the query?

Comment: there (fiddle) is showing like I want it to be but I have trouble with showing on my computer

Comment: Yes like that (result) table up, and if is posible for EKIPA & TOTALRESULT to show only 1time not 3 times?

Comment: yes thank you, just one question about that could it be separated with break row or is it just posible with comma?

Comment: actually you can change the separator by default it's comma. I don't know the seprator from break `:D`